# Using javascript in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm using javascript inside jsp page. but the js part is not loading. the js basically is tradingView chart widget.

```
        ArrayList<FXBreakListRow> list = tmpConn.selectFromFXBreakTable(query);
            if( list.size() > 0 ){

                for( FXBreakListRow tmp : list)
                {
                    %>
                    <div id="tickerChart">
                        <div  id ="chartImg">
                            <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>          
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                              new TradingView.widget({
                                      "width": 512,
                                      "height": 288,
                                      "symbol": "FX:" + tmp.getTicker(),
                                      "interval": "60",
                                      "timezone": "exchange",
                                      "theme": "White",
                                      "style": "1",
                                      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                                      "hide_top_toolbar": true,
                                      "save_image": false,
                                      "hideideas": true 
                                });
                            </script>
                            <!-- TradingView Widget END -->

                        </div>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>` should almost certainly be included only once instead of again and again every time you go around the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp.getTicker()` appears to be JSP code, but you haven't put it between `<%` and `%>` (and I'd guess you'd also need some sort of print statement to output the return value).

Comment: If i put the js part in simple HTML page i'll get a dynamic chart.

Comment: Use a javascript debugger.  Like @Quentin said, you'll likely see an error that `tmp` is undefined.  It's a server-side variable.  Try `"symbol":"FX:<%=tmp.getTicker()%>",`

Comment: yeah you right thanks. but its override the page content only the chart show up. any ideas how to fix it. thanks again.